# Dark mode in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I cannot seem to properly configure my texprofile in TeXstudio to change to dark mode. I have downloaded the `.txsprofile` from [this website](https://www.pauljhurtado.com/teaching/software.html), but upon following the instructions (saving the current profile and attempting to add the dark mode .txs file) nothing happens - I am still in the normal mode.

I am not sure what I need to post in order to better obtain help here. Could someone please advise me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit in 2021:** Since version 3 there (finally) is a built-in dark mode, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBKnQ.png).

%% original answer (applicable for version 2 and older): %%

Save the file `*.txsprofile` anywhere. Then start TeXstudio and click on
`Options->Load Profile`. Load the dark version profile and then click on
`Options->Save current setting`. Now close TeXstudio and open it again.
It should now use the dark profile:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I must not have been missing a step - I feel stupid now! Sorry.